# Building Tensorflow with Bazel: Executing genrule @png_archive//:configure failed

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I've been trying to understand why I can't build Tensorflow with Bazel.
I've been following the install instructions from the Tensorflow webpage [here](http://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.html#binary-installation).

Here's my output when I build with the command `bazel build -c opt --config=cuda --verbose_failures //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer`

```sh
[mcochrane@Matt-PC-Fedora tensorflow]$ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda --verbose_failures //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From Executing genrule @png_archive//:configure:
/home/mcochrane/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mcochrane/fd0e4dd3891f9c98b9d8308260aad0f3/tensorflow/external/png_archive/libpng-1.2.53 /home/mcochrane/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mcochrane/fd0e4dd3891f9c98b9d8308260aad0f3/tensorflow
/tmp/tmp.52xPGPoCo8 /home/mcochrane/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mcochrane/fd0e4dd3891f9c98b9d8308260aad0f3/tensorflow/external/png_archive/libpng-1.2.53 /home/mcochrane/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mcochrane/fd0e4dd3891f9c98b9d8308260aad0f3/tensorflow
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/tmp.52xPGPoCo8':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: /home/mcochrane/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mcochrane/fd0e4dd3891f9c98b9d8308260aad0f3/external/png_archive/BUILD:23:1: Executing genrule @png_archive//:configure failed: bash failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/mcochrane/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mcochrane/fd0e4dd3891f9c98b9d8308260aad0f3/tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/mcochrane/.local/bin:/home/mcochrane/bin \
  /bin/bash -c 'source tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; pushd external/png_archive/libpng-1.2.53; workdir=$(mktemp -d -t tmp.XXXXXXXXXX); cp -a * $workdir; pushd $workdir; ./configure --enable-shared=no --with-pic=no; popd; popd; cp $workdir/config.h bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/png_archive/libpng-1.2.53; rm -rf $workdir;'): bash failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/mcochrane/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mcochrane/fd0e4dd3891f9c98b9d8308260aad0f3/tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/mcochrane/.local/bin:/home/mcochrane/bin \
  /bin/bash -c 'source tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; pushd external/png_archive/libpng-1.2.53; workdir=$(mktemp -d -t tmp.XXXXXXXXXX); cp -a * $workdir; pushd $workdir; ./configure --enable-shared=no --with-pic=no; popd; popd; cp $workdir/config.h bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/png_archive/libpng-1.2.53; rm -rf $workdir;').
Target //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.229s, Critical Path: 0.71s
```

It's a bit cryptic.  Bash just fails with the following message which doesn't really provide a whole lot of insight.

```sh
bash failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/mcochrane/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mcochrane/fd0e4dd3891f9c98b9d8308260aad0f3/tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/mcochrane/.local/bin:/home/mcochrane/bin \
  /bin/bash -c 'source tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; pushd external/png_archive/libpng-1.2.53; workdir=$(mktemp -d -t tmp.XXXXXXXXXX); cp -a * $workdir; pushd $workdir; ./configure --enable-shared=no --with-pic=no; popd; popd; cp $workdir/config.h bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/png_archive/libpng-1.2.53; rm -rf $workdir;').
```

Has anyone else come across this error when compiling with bazel?

### EDIT: extra info

OS is Fedora23 (kernel 4.2.6-300.fc23)

gcc version is 5.1.1 20150618 (Red Hat 5.1.1-4) (GCC)

```sh
[mcochrane@Matt-PC-Fedora tensorflow]$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.1.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada,go,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl --enable-libmpx --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.1.1 20150618 (Red Hat 5.1.1-4) (GCC)
```

ldd version is: (GNU libc) 2.22

Comment: Can you provide the OS version, gcc -v output (version), and ldd --version output?  Also, note this line `See config.log for more details` - anything in there?

Comment: @dga I've added the extra info you mentioned.  The log file I can't find.  any ideas where it would be?  I did a search for 'config.log' in the directory I ran bazel from and from `/home/mcochrane/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mcochrane/fd0e4dd3891f9c98b9d8308260aad0f3/external/png_archive/` but no luck.

Comment: As a quick test, can you type:  `echo "int main() {}" > testme.c` and then `gcc testme.c -o testme`  to see if you can compile a basic c program?  Also, try `find /home/mcochrane/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mcochrane/fd0e4dd3891f9c98b9d8308260aad0f3/tensorflow -name 'config.log' -print'  to see if it can find the config.log file

Comment: find /home/mcochrane/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mcochrane/fd0e4dd3891f9c98b9d8308260aad0f3/t‌​ensorflow -name 'config.log' -print

Comment: @dga I ran `echo "int main() {}" > testme.c` and `gcc testme.c -o testme`, neither had any output, I was left with `testme.c` and the executable `testme` in the directory I ran them from.  I searched from the log file in `/home/mcochrane/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mcochrane/fd0e4dd3891f9c98b9d8308260aad0f3` (one dir up from the dir you suggested) by changing to that dir and running `sudo find . -name 'config.log' -print`.  It did not have any results. I also ran `sudo find / -name 'config.log' -print` to search everywhere and got no results. Seems like it just doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you get TensorFlow installed? I too had problems installing it at first but have now installed it on Windows 10, Ubuntu 15.10 and Debian 8.2 and some are VMware machines. If the OS you want it to work on doesn't work, try another that you can use for comparison. I am currently working on installing with the GPU option by dual booting with Ubuntu 15.10 which is not recommended, but so for I only had to downgrade from GCC 5.x to 4.9.

Comment: @GuyCoder I ended up getting it installed but not building from source.  I used one of the prebuild binaries.  Yeah, trying another OS is a good idea but a bit of a pain because it requires having separate dedicated hardware.  Running through a VM would seem to defeat the purpose because I don't think GPU will work through the VM.  I haven't tested that though so I could be wrong.  But in general wanting it to run as fast as possible, extra layers of abstraction surely aren't a good idea.

Comment: TensorFlow will not work in a VM using a type 2 [hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) with the GPU because the VM video driver will not have access to the GPU. The VM does not directly access the GPU but uses a means of pass through, and the pass through does not know how to pass through the GPU instructions needed for TensorFlow. I researched this to find out why and finally the only option I had for using the GPU version was to install Linux as a base OS. So for the GPU version I just installed a dual boot into Ubuntu. Hope to give the GPU version a try today.

Comment: You should leave what did as an answer. I have not tired to install TensorFlow on Fedora but would like to have another OS under my hat, pun intended. Thanks for the comment, it's nice to know that it can be done.